# Get indices of endpoints of a line in a list of 3 dimensional points

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to be able to get the indices of two endpoints that form a straight line in a list of points. It's difficult to describe so I will just say the desired outcome for multiple test cases:

Let's say we have a list of points in 3D space:

```
[45,45,45]
[45,45,42]
[45,45,39]
[45,42,39]
[45,39,39]
[45,36,39]
[45,33,39]
```

The expected outcome if the list starts at 0 would be:

```
(0,2),(3,6)
```

Because we can form a line between points on indices 0 and 2 without the line leaving the z axis, and we can form a straight line between points on indices 3 and 6 without it leaving the y axis.

The expected input will always be the same format as the above, with only 1 of the axis changing values as you go through the list. Here's another test case:

```
[30,24,42]
[30,21,42]
[27,21,42]
[27,21,45]
[27,21,48]
[27,21,51]
```

With the output:

```
(0,1),(2,5)
```

I don't know how to begin tackling the problem. I first thought of using a for loop to iterate through every point and store the difference between each consecutive point and checking whether or not the difference between the axis remained the same, but I couldn't figure out how to do it yet. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a math problem at its core. You'll need to figure that out and then ask something more specific about your _code_, not just your data. (You'll have to try something.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right, but you can try to iterate through the list of points and track the indices that form a straight line within the desired axis:

```js
function findStraightLines(points) {
  const lines = [];
  let startIdx = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    const prevPoint = points[i - 1];
    const currPoint = points[i];

    if (prevPoint[2] === currPoint[2]) {
      // The z-coordinate remains the same, form a line
      if (i - startIdx > 1) {
        lines.push(`(${startIdx},${i - 1})`);
      }
    } else {
      // The z-coordinate changes, start a new potential line
      startIdx = i;
    }
  }

  // Check if the last potential line is valid
  if (points.length - startIdx > 1) {
    lines.push(`(${startIdx},${points.length - 1})`);
  }

  return lines;
}

// Test case 1
const points1 = [
  [45, 45, 45],
  [45, 45, 42],
  [45, 45, 39],
  [45, 42, 39],
  [45, 39, 39],
  [45, 36, 39],
  [45, 33, 39]
];

console.log(findStraightLines(points1)); // Output: ["(0,2)", "(3,6)"]

// Test case 2
const points2 = [
  [30, 24, 42],
  [30, 21, 42],
  [27, 21, 42],
  [27, 21, 45],
  [27, 21, 48],
  [27, 21, 51]
];

console.log(findStraightLines(points2)); // Output: ["(0,1)", "(2,5)"]
```

The function takes in a list of points and iterates over them. It keeps track of the starting index (startIdx) of a potential line. Whenever the z-coordinate changes, it checks if the number of points between the start index and the current index is greater than 1 (indicating a straight line), and adds the line indices to the lines array. Finally, it checks if the last potential line is valid and adds it if necessary. The function returns the array of line indices.